# Help identify this 10K potentiometer?

Tags: identification, potentiometer

I need to change this potentiometer that act as an encoder in a Native Instrument controller/mixer (Kontrol S5), as it has become faulty and increases values by itself at the lower end of its range... very strange! Having it fixed by NI would cost me about 300 $US with shipping, which is prohibitive, so I am looking to do it myself, as I have some experience with de/soldering.

I have searched for countless hours but have not been able to identify it. So far I gathered that the B103 marking says it is 10K linear, but I have no clue what the 5F2 marking means.

Other useful information:

- has a center detent
- has about 300 degrees of turn
- shaft diameter 6mm and length 15mm
- runs inside a 12V device

It looks like a Bourns PTV111 series, but those have a plastic shaft versus metal on this one.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be GREATLY appreciated!

Here are images of the potentiometer :

[image: Picture 1 of potentiometer]
[image: Picture 2 of potentiometer]
[image: Picture 3 of potentiometer]
[image: Picture 4 of potentiometer]

Comment: It has the amount of pins you'd associate with a rotary encoder. But the limited degrees of turn tell otherwise. The single detent might indicate a custom part number (non catalog).

Comment: 4 pins is indeed odd for an audio pot. Also doesn't look to be near any opamp stages (unless they are on the reverse)? Put a scope on the pins and see what it is doing. May well be an encoder with reduced angle to feel like an audio pot.

Comment: It might very well be an encoder, it is used to change values (0 to 100) on a digital FX channel. What throws me of is that it specifies B103, that I associate more with a potentiometer than an encoder. If it is indeed a custom part, I would be kind of screwed, wouldn't I?

Comment: Ask the manufacturer if they will sell you a couple.  I bought parts direct from Kenwood in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RobertEndl. I tried that, but the manufacturer, Native Instruments, is really not interested in selling me parts, and none of their local resellers can get parts from them anymore. Not a very good customer service strategy IMHO.

Comment: Have you found the potentiometer and did you solve your problem ?
I have the same problem…
Thanks for your help [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOjRc.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOjRc.jpg)

Comment: @FabienBitoun  This is not an answer to the question so, I'm afraid, it has been flagged for deletion. Please take the [Tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how the   site works and then you can ask your own question.

Comment: @FabienBitoun  The OP has not been back for a long while. The existing answers probably tell you what you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a potentiometer with a center tap output on the extra pin, like this one:

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/15/RK11K11_VARIETYOTHER-253030.pdf

"5F2" most likely refers to the package options like shaft length and if the detent is present or not, but you'd need a datasheet from the original manufacturer to be certain.

I think you'll have to remove the existing one and use a multimeter to determine the pin assignments (for wiper, center tap) in order to find a suitable replacement from another manufacturer, like the Alps part I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

This was the only similar thing I was able to find, there is a small difference at shaft's base but not sure if it's because "The drawing and specification are for reference only."

http://docdro.id/15rpUdT

The other alternative is as you said, **Bourns PTV111**. Available on eBay as spare potentiometer for "NATIVE INSTRUMENTS TRAKTOR KONTROL X1 Z1 F1 S2 S4 MKI - MKII". (not S5 though).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Having 4 pins makes this more likely a rotary encoder.

Searching for "5F2 encoder" will bring up hits for devices by TE Connectivity that look similar.

Comment: Notice that the OP was quite specific: "*- has a [one] center detent [indicating the mid-position]
- has about 300 degrees of turn*".